# How to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ given $\mathbb{P}(X=k, Y=m)={\frac{1}{36}}\cdot\left( {\frac{5}{6}} \right)^{k-2}$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X,Y$ be random variables, s.t for $1\leq m<k$ $$\mathbb{P}(X=k, Y=m)={\frac{1}{36}}\cdot\left( {\frac{5}{6}} \right)^{k-2}$$
Calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$

I am not sure even how to approach it, so far I wrote the definition of $\mathbb{E}$ but I am not sure how to write the indexes of $k$ and $m$

Comment: For future info, do not use displaystyle in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I suggest you to tell us any detail that you hidden

- the random variables are discrete and integer
- the support is

$$1\leq y<x<\infty$$

Now you can start in calculating the marginals. I start in calcuating

$$P(Y=y)=\frac{1}{36}\sum_{x=y+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-2}=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{y-1}$$

where $y=1,2,3,...$

Thus $Y\sim Geo(1/6)$  with expectation $E(Y)=6$

(in this case the Geometric distribution counts the trials before the first success. It is always important to explain if the geometric distribution counts the trials or the failures)

Now you can proceed by yourself

Comment: Thank you, I did not hide anything this is the exactly question I got so I do not know if the variables are discretes and integer

Comment: I would like for a small hint how do I find $P(X=x)$, I am stuck on the expression $P(X=x)=\frac{1}{36}\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-2}$. I don't have any dependends on m so it seems that the series diverge

Answer (score 1):

> I would like for a small hint how do I find $P(X=x)$...

It is very very easy...if you sum the joint pmf summing the y's you get

$$P(X=x)=\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-2}\cdot\sum_{y=1}^{x-1}1=(x-1)\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-2}$$

That is

$$P(X=x)=\binom{x-1}{2-1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-2}$$

where $x=2,3,4,5,...$

this is a Negative Binomial, counting the number of trial to get 2 successes, thus

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=2\times6=12$$

---

As an exercise, before getting in calculations, you could prove that your $p(X,Y)$ is a nice joint pmf. This exercise is very useful because it exactly lets you know which is the support. Once you understand where your joint probability function is defined, you are immediately able to understand the problem and thus the solution.

I suggest you to change the index letter in $X=x$ and $Y=y$ because inserting to many letters in the equation can get you in confusion.

$$\sum_{x=2}^{\infty}\sum_{y=1}^{x-1}\frac{1}{36}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-2}=\sum_{x=2}^{\infty}\frac{x-1}{36}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-2}=1$$